# Cakephp Ajax Button

Tags: ajax, facebook, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a delete button. which on click it should visit a url like /delete/{id} and once the response from that url is true. i want to delete the comment box like in facebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wont add any extra than Leo's comment, but I will explain with some code. Presume that you are using jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr a.delete').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), null, function(response){
            if(response == 'ok'){ //you should invent how to get 'ok' or other string identifying that the deletion is successful.
                 link.parents('tr').remove();
            } else {
                 alert('There is a problem while deleting this element');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

if you put this code on your project it will handle all links which had .delete class and are in a table row.

There are two things which you should do:

1. You need to pass some string in
   order to detect if the operation is
   successful or not. In my example I
   would print "ok" on success
   deletion.
2. If your table has pagination, it wont
   rebuild the table, while it just
   will remove the row from the table.
   and if you have let's say 5 rows per
   page and you delete all of them the
   page will remain empty while there
   will be other records in the table.
   That's why instead of removing the
   tr I would reload the whole page.

In that case the code for successful deletion will look like this:

```
if(response == 'ok'){
   $('#content').load(window.location);
}
```

The script is not optimised, but it will give you the ideas how to achieve your ideas.

HTH

Comment: thanks Nik, i question. how to send back some kinda data when the deleteing is completed and error data when it couldnt delete. so that i can display that in an alert box.

Comment: Just go to your controller's delete action and type echo 'ok';die(); or 'error';die(); and that's it and remove the redirects just in case.

Answer (score 3):

So write an onClick event handler in your view, a php delete method on the appropriate controller called by the event handler and a javascript action to perform when the ajax call returns success.